# How can I use MiniMap3DExtension with IFC file?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I've checked that MiniMap3DExtension can be used with Revit file. (I referred to this link -> https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/add-revit-levels-and-2d-minimap-your-3d)
But I can't use MiniMap3DExtension with IFC file.
How can I use MiniMap3DExtension with IFC file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this before loading `Autodesk.AEC.Minimap3DExtension`

```js
await viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.AEC.LevelsExtension', { ifcLevelsEnabled: true } );
```

Or enable `ifcLevelsEnabled` while creating viewer instance

```js
const config3d = {
  extensions: [
    'Autodesk.AEC.LevelsExtension'
  ],
  ifcLevelsEnabled: true
};
viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(htmlDiv, config3d);
viewer.start();
```

If you have loaded `Autodesk.AEC.LevelsExtension` before, you need to reload it to take effect.

```js
viewer.unloadExtension( 'Autodesk.AEC.LevelsExtension' )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @Eason Kang!
MiniMap3DExtension can now be used with my IFC files.